# Certificate verification failed. While docker image build in nodejs

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a docker image but getting error. it's failing on RUN apt-get update. code sample is given below.

```
# Update packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common make g++
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

`Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.`

I am also tried to put below code but facing same issue.

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates

sudo update-ca-certificates

sudo apt-get update
```

Anyone can help on this.

Comment: Did you tried to update ca-certificates in the container or in the hosting machine ?

Comment: check if apt sources are https or not